# Parse XML with jQuery from URL

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to get back "jmeno" from this XML (http://stagservices.upol.cz/ws/services/rest/student/getStudentInfo?osCislo=R140742) and I get back error everytime.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://stagservices.upol.cz/ws/services/rest/student/getStudentInfo?osCislo=R140742',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: parseXml,
        error: function () {
            alert("Error: Something went wrong");
        }
    });
});

function parseXml(xml) {
    $(xml).find('student').each(function () {
        $("#output").append($(this).find('jmeno').text() + "<br />");
    });
}
```

Comment: Tru using `.parseXML()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: May be the error is the cross domain web security form the browser

Comment: Has it any solution?

Comment: if it's only for testing, you can temporarily disable cross domain web security on your browser.

Comment: I have to use this function at website.

Comment: 1) As mentioned, CORS restrictions mean you can't do an XML HTTP Request to another server without some other stuff... the simplest workaround is to setup a proxy on the server hosting your javascript to make the request to the external server for you.  
2) What is the error you get? (Hint: you will need to modify your code to get it... yes, I get that right now you just get an alert popup)

Comment: Enable cross-origin on server to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://Petr)**

Use `datatype: 'xml'`.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://stagservices.upol.cz/ws/services/rest/student/getStudentInfo?osCislo=R140742',
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function () {
              alert("Error: Something went wrong");
          }
      });
  });
```