# Parse XML issues

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xml, atom-feed

So, I'm leaving the live xml/atom-feed url as something different. It's hosted on LiveJournal, but I don't want to give that link away.
Anyways, I seem to have something confused or my understanding is confused on how this works:

```
let XML_URL = "https://users.livejournal.com/<username>/data/atom";


$(function(){

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(XML_URL); 
        
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    
        // Find Person Tag
    var $entry = $xml.find("entry");
    
    $entry.each(function(){
        
        var title = $(this).find('title').text(),
            content = $(this).find('content').text();
        
        $("#items" ).html(title+ ' <br /> <br />' +content);
        
    });

});
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-us'>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/xmlreader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="style">
    <div id="items"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So what am I missing here? Do I need to to read the file itself? If I do.. how do I do so?

EDIT: So, the link provided by @freedomn-m gave me part of the answer I needed. It works, the trouble is now CORS (which i temporarily disabled on my browser to get it working). Im using cloudflare but i can't seem to get the transform rules to allow my site to access the XML file on LiveJournal, even though livejournal allows access to the file. Then, again, i'm not even sure if i even need to mess with the transform rules on cloudflare for this to work.

Comment: `$.parseXML()` expects the XML content itself, not the URL of where it can be found.

Comment: Ok, so what am I supposed to do to read the contents of the file, and parse it?

Comment: Possibly the `fetch()` API, but you may have to do it from a server if the target URL does not allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: _"but I don't want to give that link away"_ - if you put this into publicly available client-side JavaScript, then you're still basically giving it away.

Comment: *what am I supposed to do to read the contents of the file, and parse it* - in addition to `fetch()` use `$.ajax` to read from a URL and parse, example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397559/parse-xml-with-jquery-from-url   You may get a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issue.

Comment: If you want to avoid "giving away the link", you will need some kind of small proxy/script on your server that fetches/outputs (and maybe caches) the feed. This will avoid CORS issues, too.

Comment: Ok SO! @freedomn-m you helped me with this a lot, especially leading me to a CORS issue. If I disabled CORS on my browser, everything worked according the the example code you linked.
New issue is getting cloudflare to allow that requested resource to be read.

ALSO, for those saying I am not able to hide the real link, i have a redirect on cloudflare that hides the real link so all i need to do is use /blogview and it works. The  semi-real link above was used so that everyone knew what i was trying to access

Answer (score 0):

[parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) parses a string into an XML document.

Example from the documentation:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.parseXML demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p id="someElement"></p>
<p id="anotherElement"></p>
 
<script>
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>",
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find( "title" );
 
// Append "RSS Title" to #someElement
$( "#someElement" ).append( $title.text() );
 
// Change the title to "XML Title"
$title.text( "XML Title" );
 
// Append "XML Title" to #anotherElement
$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $title.text() );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

So you will need to load the actual XML as a string and pass that using `parseXML` rather than the URL that point to where the file is located. You either download it on server-side and generate it into your HTML/JS with the help of the server, or download it via Javascript, as long as your CSP and CORS settings allow you to send requests to the source.

Comment: The problem is that the xml auto updates as things are posted to the "blog" or journal.
so how can i read the xml from a separate file and load it into ```parseXML``` dynamically

Comment: @SilverWolfe you can repeatedly request the file from time to time and always compare the result to the last decoded XML and if it changed, then parse the new XML again. But, before we make it dynamic, first let's solve it in some manner. Let's break the problem into two subproblems. The first being that there is a file you need to download and parse. We need to solve this first. Is this already working well for you? Because if so, then we can switch to the second problem, that is, making sure this works in a dynamic manner.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not the one making it dynamic. It's hosted on livejournal.com, anytime I make an entry in their server, the xml/atom-feed updates. I have my own site in which I want to display the entries (say, up to 3 entries), which they allow, instead of linking directly to the site itself. (Though, I will provide a link to the hosting site, of course)

Comment: @SilverWolfe independently of who makes it dynamic, we need a reliable way to download and parse a static XML first and when that works, we need to make it dynamic. We should solve a single problem at a time. We first need to make sure that your code is correct in downloading and parsing XML. When that's done, then we need to focus on the dynamicity of the problem.